# How do you check if a user has completed Membership Screening in discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord, discord.py

In Discord, there is a setting for servers called "Membership Screening". With the MEE6 bot, it has an option to automatically give a role only after a user has accepted the Membership Screening. In discord.py rewrite, how could I make it wait for a user to accept the Membership Screening before carrying out an action? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Member.pending`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.pending) attribute to check if member have completed member verification.
Also you can use [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event to give a role when member completes verification.
For example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.pending and not after.pending:
        pass  # give a role
```